# Problem on calculating trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus

im trying to solve the following integral:
$ \int_{}^{}\frac{7x+2}{\sqrt{1-25x^2}}\: dx $ with 2 different substitutions and im getting different results:

1. $-\frac{7}{25}\sqrt{1-25x^2}-\frac{2}{5}cos^{-1}(5x) + C$
2. $-\frac{7}{25}\sqrt{1-25x^2}+\frac{2}{5}sin^{-1}(5x)+C$

Why is that ? The substitutions I made are $5x=cosu$ and $5x=sinu$.

Comment: $\sin^{-1}u$ is a vertical shift of $-\cos^{-1}u$, so these are actually the same. Just remember that the $C$ in each answer are not equal to each other (they are $\pi /2$ apart).